# Deserializing random json file in c#

Tags: c#, json

i am trying to take in a json file and iterate over some of the values.
The file is 73000 lines long, and i only need a few values.

Here is an example of the json file:

```
 {
    "value" : "key"
    "value" : "key"
    "Owner": {
        "UserId": xxx,
        "Username": "xxx",
    },
    "Items": [
        {
        "value": "key",
        "value": "key",
        "Comment": "",
        "value": {
            "value": {
                "value": "key",
                "value": "key",
                "value": "key",
            }
        },
        "CustomFields": [
            {
                "Name": "something",
                "Content": "true"
            }
            ]
        }
        ]
}
```

How do i load this in without defining the object? i need 5 values per item, from different nesting levels, though i dont want to define the class as the file is more than 70.000 lines.

I tried doing it like this:
`var values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(json)`;

But that way i will get an error when i try to itterate over items, as items value will now be a string!

```
foreach (Dictionary<string, string> result in values["items"])
```

Is there a way to load the file, defining the class based on the json schema?
I need values from different levels in the file, some at root level some nested.

Comment: Deserialize to `JObject`, or create classes to deserialize it that just contain the fields you want to extract. Or take the more efficient (but harder) approach and read it manually using a `JsonReader`.

Comment: Thanks! so if i am understanding you correctly, i could create a class with the same name fields, and structure as the ones in my json, and then only extract theese values into my object? seems like the more elegant soloution. It will then extract based on key names i assume?

Comment: Yeah, that's correct. :)